# Getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET Intermittently with Node API Hosted in IIS using IISNODE

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

I have a video streaming API developed in Node.js using the Express module.

This API is hosted on my local machine under IIS 8.5 using iisnode module, which makes the IIS as my reverse proxy server and the express (node) as my web server.

When I hit my API URL in the browser, it plays the video for a while and then I get ***net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET*** error.

I get this error after few minutes (approx 7 mins.), but there is no specific time duration observed.

I see below two errors in HTTPERR folder under ***"C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\"***.

> 2019-05-09 14:55:39 ::1%0 64836 ::1%0 3005 HTTP/1.1 GET /api/videolib/streamvideo?id=f80b4ae0725f11e9b42fcb6803fde91b - 8 Connection_Dropped VideoLibrary.WebAPI.Node
>
> 2019-05-10 08:51:02 ::1%0 54848 ::1%0 3005 HTTP/1.1 GET /api/videolib/streamvideo?id=f80b4ae0725f11e9b42fcb6803fde91b - 8 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue VideoLibrary.WebAPI.Node

I have observed that, I don't get this error at all when I run the API directly under Node.exe thus bypassing the IIS and IISNODE altogether on my local machine.

However, I have no choice but to use IIS and IISNODE in production.

**UPDATE:**

So, I created an API in .NET equivalent to my node API, and hosted it in the IIS; it works fine without issues of any kind.
Now, I know that there is something weird going on with the iisnode module.

I have tried changing couple of settings in iisnode via web.config, but nothing seems to fix this problem.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To me, this looks like a case of request/queue size overshoot. Please check the size of the video. If you could run a url with a smaller size video without any issues, you could narrow down the issue to size constraints. The app pool advanced settings have a queue length property which can be adjusted to see if it solves this issue.

Comment: Yes, it works fine for smaller video size. I tested a video of 18 mins. and less, and I don't get any error. I tried increasing the Queue Length, but that doesn't seem to fix this issue. Thanks.